# Azure SQL Database vs Azure SQL on VM

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine

We are finding Azure SQL Database very slow. Its probably about 10x slower than the same spend on a SQL on an Azure VM.

However a VM based solution requires maintenance and backups and im concerned I'll loose the VM and data if something horrible goes wrong.

Thus the SQL Azure solution seems safer to me. So I have two specific questions.

1. Are you seeing this speed difference and if so is there a solution
2. Is there any nice solution for ensure the SQL on VM is backed up automatically and offsite.

Comment: Performance is subjective, but... you should probably edit your question to describe the SQL Database tier, as well as the VM size (and quantity) you're comparing with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure SQL database is slightly slower than SQL Server on Azure Virtual Machine. However, we didn't find it as slow as 10X. May be you should try Premium tier,  which delivers more powerful and predictable performance, in case your database is in some other tier.

Regarding SQL Server on Azure Virtual Machine, there is support available for automated backup and patching. Please visit the below link for more details.

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/01/29/automated-everything-with-sql-server-on-iaas-vms/

Comment: We are on the top tier P3 and its 10x slower. Unbelievable but true. And the VM im comparing it to is 1/2 the price of the P3 Azure solution.

Answer (score 2):

While performance analysis, it is worth checking for ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait type. Make Sure your client application is deployed close to your database in Azure.